# I guess vs. I think

Tags: word-choice, difference

Dear teachers and fellow learners,

I am a proofreader of online novels in China. When correcting the unidiomatic expressions used by translators working for me, I encountered one that goes like this:

> I **guessed** she might be the one who could help.

For some unknown reasons, I think the proper verb here should be 'think', which makes the sentence “I thought she might be the one who could help”. If there has to be a reason, I would say 'might' already speaks of the possibility. Could anyone please kindly tell me if I am correct or not?

Comment: What is the problem with "guess" being used with "might"? Isn't it actually more correlative  than think?

Answer (score 2):

I think either word is grammatically correct, and either one makes sense. Using "guess" implies to me that the choice is more intuitive than reasoned, but I wouldn't regard it as a strong implication. I think native speakers might use either word in the same situation. (Or do I guess that? 8>)

Answer (score 0):

Neither is more correct grammatically, but the meaning of the sentence may be altered. Both words have the same intention - implying a less than definite assertion - but may be perceived differently.

The example statement, "I guessed she might be the one who could help" may be perceived by a native speaker as: not caring, indifferent, or not having put any thought into your reasoning.

This can be important when speaking to a person of authority and using similar phrases with the verbs: think, assume, and guess. It is best to preface the statement with a reason for your thought, assumption, or guess. If your boss asks you when a project with will be done, "Based on how long the last one took me, **I think** I will be done tomorrow" is better than "**I think** I will be done tomorrow."